# How to know what I am using Hera 5.1.2?

Tags: system

I recently installed 5.1 and now 5.1.2 has come out, I keep the updates up to date, but in the section about, I still get 5.1, how do I know that I have updated to 5.1.2.

Thank you. Greetings.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you found what there is to find. Whether you look in System Settings > About, or through the command line in Terminal with `lsb_release -a`, the most you will see is the major and minor release numbers. In this case, 5.1.

The final number is used by the elementary team, but it doesn't display within the operating system. So long as you install the available updates through AppCenter, you are up-to-date.

Answer (score 0):

I just figured this out recently.  Hope this helps.

Press Win+Space
Type"  About"
Select the About icon

The version of eOS you are using will appear on the left under the logo.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Hi. If that section is where I commented, but there is only 5.1, so I see it strange, I should put 5.1.2, right ?.

Thank you.

Greetings.